# In bootstrap, how can you have two rows in one column and single rows in other?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am looking to implement the following table where the name column uses two rows while age and location uses one. The text would be centered in their own row:

[image]

Is this bootstrap compliant? If so, how would you implement such a table?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure you need bootstrap rows for this? You could just use a line break, eg. $name<br>$position as the name column's value, and set a vertical-align:middle style attribute on the TDs of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can nest rows and columns in bootstrap. The markup would look something like this.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h1>Name</h1>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <p>John Smith</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <p>Contractor</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h1>Age</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h1>Location</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```